# scp directory from remote ubuntu desktop to virtual machine

Tags: ssh, virtualization, scp

I want to transfer my project to a virtual machine. I have mac book, so I logged in to my Ubuntu 18.04 remote desktop. Still, I can't transfer my project directory to the virtual machine. I have moved my folder to the ubuntu desktop, and I thought that this command should work:

`scp -r /home/parallels/Desktop/project/* snf-842537.vm.okeanos.grnet.gr:project`

However, I get `No such file or directory` message in my terminal. What do you think I should try?

Thank you

Comment: have you tried specifying a path on your vm?

Comment: @guiverc You should turn that into an answer

Answer (score 1):

Well, I feel like you don't need the wildcharacter. As long as you give the path of your directory, it will include all the files on it. Moreover you haven't defined your username for the okeanos VM( user@snf-xxxxx) and I am not sure if the syntax of the path you are using is correct (if you have the folder in your root directory you should use /project)

If your don't feel comfortable with the command line and the scp command, try to use a file transfer tool with a user interface.
WinSCP is great for windows. For your mac you can try Cyberduck https://cyberduck.io/